# How to use one MediaCodec instance to decode multiple AAC streams

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

The mission is decoding AAC frames sent from a chat room. The device receives AAC frames from different senders. And it knows whom each frame from. I need a decoder to convert AAC to PCM, so I can do audio mixing work then.

How can I do that?
My idea is to use MediaCodec with a streamId queue. If I put one AAC into the decoder, enqueue its streamId. Then I finally retrieve an output from MediaCodec, dequeue one streamId.

My problem is, the MediaCodec, if I successfully feed N frames, I can only get (N - 2) output frames. It seems wrong.
What's the correct way to do that?